# Constant DHCP Requests with Cisco vWLC and Cisco 3560 setup

Tags: dhcp, cisco-catalyst, cisco-wlc

I'm having an issue identifying why my Cisco vWLC with DHCP bridging is flooding my DHCP servers with REQUESTS. These requests are coming in well over 1000/min.
[image]
My Setup is in a lab, I am running a Cisco vWLC(v8.0.152) trunked to a Cisco 3560(v15.0(2)SE11) switch. The Wireless Client VLAN 107 (10.22.252.0/24) exists on both the Cisco vWLC and the Cisco 3560. There is a helper-address on the Cisco 3560 with the DHCP server defined(10.22.168.4).

What is really odd is the devices asking constantly for DHCP Request, are assigned an IP address.

**DHCP Proxy has been disabled on the vWLC**
[image]

**Switch SVI has a address-helper defined.**

[image]

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Still happening. This flooding is utilizing almost 100Mbs...

Comment: Those two hosts need to be checked. Unfortunately, host configurations are off-topic here. You may find an answer on [sf].

Answer (score -1):

You are seeing two mac addresses. They are most likely bouncing the packet between them.  Identify the other device and check it's ip helper setup.  Or your route is messed up.

Comment: The MAC address you are seeing is from the two clients requesting DHCP.

Comment: There are very few failures which will cause that level of utilization.  DHCP will never retransmit at that rate.  The only things that cause this symptom are layer 2 loops.  Unplug the DHCP server, your problem will not go away.  Unplug the clients, the problem will not go away.  you have a loop elsewhere.